# Typo3 backend loading problems: No module found

Tags: php, typo3, backend

I've got a strange problem with my current typo3 installation, I've never had before. I'm not able to access the backend anymore due to the following error appearing when I'm trying to access the backend.

> Module loader
>
> No module found. If this is a temporary error, please reload the Backend!

Of course, reloading didn't help at all. I've already tried installing it on a different system to check out if the problem could be caused by my local apache/php installtion. Unfortunately it didn't change anything. The typo3 install tools doesn't tell me anything about error or a broken configuration. :/
So I thought it might be a good idea to go and look for some log files. Unfortunately, the only log file I could find (typo3temp/logs/typo3.log) is completely empty and the the php logfile also doesn't tell me anything interesting. Maybe one of you guys has an idea how I could find out what the problem could be? Or at least get some error messages? Unfortunately I could not find too much information about people dealing with the same problem. Thank you! :)

Comment: Does this happen for an editor or an admin user? Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: did you empty typo3temp and clear all caches in the install tool? That's the 1st thing I do when the backend doesn't load

Comment: PS please post your version via the tags (eg typo3-7.6.x)

Comment: Check your `typo3conf/PackageStates.php` - Are all extensions are set to `inactive` or not listed? That is usually the cause for me when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers!
The problem was as simple as it can be. It turned out that my user just didn't have any admin access and that is why I could not find anyone else with the same weird problem. I was told that my account was an admin account, so I didn't even think about this as a possible problem. 
Sorry guys for bothering your with such a question!

Yours Sincerely, 
Felix